# Table not getting created in database

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am using below hibernate configuration and when I call create method from Postman client, then instead of creating table and inserting values into database, I am getting SQLGrammerException. Please check below configuration and let me know what I can do to create a table and update it ?

configuration_file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">
    <bean id="dbPropertyConfigurer"
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/db_config.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Database Properties -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close"
                p:driverClass="${jdbc.driver.className}"
                p:jdbcUrl="${jdbc.url}"
                p:user="${jdbc.username}"
                p:password="${jdbc.password}"               
                />
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> 
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.entity" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

Pojo class contains JPA annotations @Id, @Column for defining column and primary keys and @Entity and @Table for defining table and entity values.

Comment: I could be wrong, but does `${jdbc.hibernate.dialect}` need to be quoted to be evaluated?

Comment: No, it will not be because if i create table manually then everything is working fine.

Comment: add the stack trace & the code that triggered the hibernate operations

Comment: @tharindu_DG thanks for you help, but i found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the mentioned configuration is incorrect.

```
<prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
```

The above should be -

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
```

and its done.

Answer (score 0):

If the table does not exist and you want to create it through hibernate then you should set `hbm2ddl` value to `create`(`<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>`)